# How to extract some values in a column and calculate them, then generate a new column in linux

Tags: linux

Here is my vcf file, now I want to extract some values form the last column V350092589_L01_84 to creat new columns.

```
    #CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  V350092589_L01_84
    chr19   11224265        .       A       G       23868.64        PASS    AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;DP=3417;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=8.538;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=41.37;MQRankSum=1.59;QD=7.57;ReadPosRankSum=9.38;SOR=0.783          GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:2029,1125:3154:99:23876,0,49821
    chr19   11227576        .       C       T       8055.64         PASS    AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;DP=1025;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=3.316;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=41.34;MQRankSum=-4.736e+00;QD=9.12;ReadPosRankSum=2.55;SOR=0.982    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:533,350:883:99:8063,0,15924
```

Specifically.

1. Extracting the sub-column DP=xxxx which is in the last column and generating a new column.
2. Extract the sub-column AD: 2092, 1125; AD: 553, 350 and calculate a ratio value, e.g. Ratio=1125/(1125+2092), Ratio=350/(350+553). Then take the Ratio value and generate a new column

Then,combine the two columns to a new csv file, like this

```
DP     Ratio
3154   0.34
883    0.38
```

Comment: the DP= values are DP=3417 and DP=1025 but in your answer it's the column behind  the ratio ones … so which one is it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in `awk`, but your numbers seem to be off by `0.02` (see below for reason). For instance, you can do:

```bash
awk '
  FNR==1 {                    # if first record
    printf "DP\tRatio\n"      # output heading
    next                      # skip to next record
  } 
  {
    nf = $NF                  # save copy of last field
    gsub (/[,:]/, " ", nf)    # replace "," and ":" with " "
    split (nf, arr, " ")      # split into arr on space
    printf "%s\t%.2f\n", arr[4], arr[3]/(arr[2]+arr[3])  # output result
  }
' file
```

Where for example with record 2, `arr[3] == 1125`, and `arr[2] == 2029`. The result of the computation is `0.36` not `0.34`? (you used `2092` in your calculation instead of the actual `2029` and `553` instead of the actual `533` -- mystery solved)

**Example Use/Output**

You can just paste the script into an xterm with your data file (named `file` or whatever you change the filename to) as:

```
$ awk '
>   FNR==1 {                    # if first record
>     printf "DP\tRatio\n"      # output heading
>     next                      # skip to next record
>   }
>   {
>     nf = $NF                  # save copy of last field
>     gsub (/[,:]/, " ", nf)    # replace "," and ":" with " "
>     split (nf, arr, " ")      # split into arr on space
>     printf "%s\t%.2f\n", arr[4], arr[3]/(arr[2]+arr[3])  # output result
>   }
> ' file
DP      Ratio
3154    0.36
883     0.40
```

So the output based on the file with the fields split as shown above is:

```
DP      Ratio
3154    0.36
883     0.40
```

**Creating an Awk Script**

Creating a script with `awk` to run from the command line is a convenient way to make the `awk` commands reusable. For example you can create a file say, `splitrec.awk` containing:

```
#!/bin/awk

FNR == 1 {                  # if first record
  printf "DP\tRatio\n"      # output heading
  next                      # skip to next record
}
{
  nf = $NF                  # save copy of last field
  gsub (/[,:]/, " ", nf)    # replace "," and ":" with " "
  split (nf, arr, " ")      # split into arr on space
  printf "%s\t%.2f\n", arr[4], arr[3]/(arr[2]+arr[3])  # output result
}
```

Then your use of the script becomes:

```
$  awk -f splitrec.awk file
DP      Ratio
3154    0.36
883     0.40
```

Comment: Thank you @ David C.Rankin, I executed your solution and it worked fine. Actually, I want to save the result to a csv file. I just modified the script as lowing: gsub (/[,:]/, " ,", nf), split (nf, arr, " , "). I'm not sure if it is a good change.

Comment: Now I find that the number of columns I am interested in has increased, including the REF, ALT columns and GQ sub-columns. If I want to extract them in the following order, e.g. REF, ALT,DP, tRatio, GQ and finally save the extracted results to a comma-separated file called test.csv. How do I make the changes according to the script you have provided? For example printf "REF\ALT\DP\tRatio\GQ\n" , is that right?

Comment: `REF`, `ALT` and `QUAL` are fields `4, 5, 6` so they are `$4`, `$5` and `$6` in `awk`. If I wanted to write the same output with the addition of `REF`, `ALT` and `QUAL` in .csv form, I'd add to `printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%.2f\n", $4,$5,$6,arr[4], arr[3]/(arr[2]+arr[3])`. That would write `REF`, `ALT`, `QUAL`, `DP`, `Ratio` out. You will need to add to the header output in the first `printf()`.  (also your change to `gsub (/[,:]/, " ,", nf), split (nf, arr, " , ").` is just another way to skin the cat. If it works with your actual data, that's fine -- not sure why you include spaces.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to extract out the fields, the rest is trivial :

```
{m,g} '!_<NR ? sub(OFS, _, $!(NF=NF)) : $_="DP\tRatio" ' \
                   OFS='\t'                               \
       FS='^.*;DP=|[;][^ \t]+[ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+[^:]+:|[0-9]+:[0-9]+,.*,.*$|[:,]'
```

```
DP      Ratio
3417    2029  1125  3154        
1025    533   350   883
```

A less intuitive way of doing it would be (adding `NF` check to protect blank lines)

```
{m,g}awk '+_~NF ? !_ : !_<NR ? sub(".",_,$!--NF)--NF : $_="DP\tRatio"'
```